# MERGE with multiple possible different updates

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Table `STORAGE`:

```
ProductID, MediumPrice, BestPrice, WorstPrice
```

Imagine I run a query on a Table XX that returns `ProductID` and the uptodate `MediumPrice`.

So with MERGE I would like to:

1. Update the `STORAGE.MediumPrice` if it's different than the `XX.MediumPrice`
2. Update the `STORAGE.BestPrice` if the `XX.MediumPrice` is lower
3. Update `STORAGE.WorstPrice` if the `xx.MediumPrice` is higher

and I know I cannot have multiple `WHEN MATCHED` (:

Comment: So what have you tried? Sounds like a job for a stored procedure to me

Comment: I tried various things but it seems I might have found an answer

Answer (score 2):

```
MERGE STORAGE AS ST  
   USING (SELECT ProductID, MediumPrice FROM XX) AS X1  
    ON ST.ProductID = X1.ProductID  
WHEN MATCHED THEN                   
   UPDATE SET ST.MediumPrice = X1.MediumPrice,   
              ST.BestPrice =  CASE WHEN (ST.BestPrice > X1.MediumPrice)  
                              THEN X1.MediumPrice ELSE ST.BestPrice END,  
              ST.WorstPrice = CASE WHEN (ST.WorstPrice < X1.MediumPrice)   
                              THEN X1.MediumPrice ELSE ST.WorstPrice END
```

========================================
This seems to fix the issue ..I think !!